# REGEX for IP address which is incomplete

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a form where I'm storing IP address.
The form validations must have 3 conditions.

1. Where the user has to enter the entire IP eg:(100.10.10.100)
2. Where the user enters the first 2 parts and put a star * in the remaining fields eg: (100.10.*. *)
3. Where the user enters the first 3 parts and put a star * in the last field eg:(100.10.10.*)

My form looks like this

```
<form method="post" class="get-ip" action="action.php" name="get-ip" id="get-ip">
  <label for="ip-address">Enter IP Address</label>
  <input type="text" class="ip-address" id="ip-address" name="ip-address">
  <input type="submit" class="submit-ip" name="submit-ip" value="Submit IP">
</form>
```

My validation looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit-ip"])){
  $ip = $_POST["ip-address"];
  $ipCheck = '/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/';
  if(preg_match($ipCheck, $ip)){
    /*Do something*/
  }
}
```

This is how far I've been.
I can validate if the IP is real or not, but I'm stuck on the 2nd and 3rd point as I don't have any REGEX that matches those conditions.

EDIT
I've managed to get the third REGEX which is

```
$thirdCondition = '/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[*]?)$/';
```

I'm stuck on the 2nd condition now

Comment: Have three regexes. Much easier to handle

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan. This isn’t performance-critical code, and sometimes more code is better. You could also explode the string on `.` and just write a couple of `if` statements so that it is super-obvious what this does in the future.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know how to make regex can you help me with it

Comment: Regex101.com is a great resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 3 regexex

```
$first_condition = '/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\z/';
$second_condition = '/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.[*]\z/';
$third_condition = '/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.[*]\.[*]\z/';
```